# Razor Pages models return null for model properties that are classes

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core

In my Razor project I have two classes as follows:

```
namespace reftest.Models
{
    public class Details
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int IQ { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Details Particulars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I added a Scaffolding Item as per the tutorial which created Create, Delete, Details, Edit and Index pages as usual. These work correctly as far as the Name field is concerned. I can create new Person records, edit them, etc. Age and IQ were not displayed. No problem - I went into the Create.cshtml and added the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Person.Particulars.Age" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Person.Particulars.Age" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Person.Particulars.Age" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

For the corresponding controller I changed nothing but here it is for reference:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly reftest.Models.reftestContext _context;

    public CreateModel(reftest.Models.reftestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Person.Add(Person);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

It displayed a text box for Age and when I entered a value and submitted the new record, it was preserved. I know this by looking at the DB records where I can see a row in the Details table and a corresponding (and correct) Id number for that record in the Particulars column of the Person table.

However, no matter what I do I cannot retrieve it as part of the Person model. The value for Particulars is always Null. For example on the Details page I have this:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person.Particulars.Age)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Person.Particulars.Age)
    </dd>
</dl>
```

which always displays an empty field. In the corresponding .cshtml.cs file I have this:

```
public class DetailsModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly reftest.Models.reftestContext _context;

    public DetailsModel(reftest.Models.reftestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Person = await _context.Person.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (Person == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Person.Particulars is always returned as null. It simply doesn't populate it. But I can see the correct data and foreign key in the database. How can I get it to populate?

Comment: It looks like your question is more to do with the `Person` object having a `null` value because it is not being properly constructed. You might want to take a closer look at your object relationships and how that is managed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you saying that I need to explicitly put a Constructor on Person that will query the database for related Details records and build the Details instance itself? I'm very new to Razor Pages and I assumed the framework would handle Entity relationships automatically as it does in, for example, Django. I can make a Constructor that populates each related class if need be but I thought I wouldn't need to. To be clear, the code to create a new instance correctly populated the database with both Person and Details records so it can create but not retrieve?

Comment: Actually, I think you are mixing up ideas here... Razor Pages and Entity Framework (EF) are separate issues. In your question you talk about Razor Pages as the culprit for your issue, but my comment is to tell you to look at EF in specific to solve your problem.

Comment: I would recommend you look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio and then maybe come back with a new question?

Comment: Thanks.I saw that there were both Razor pages and MVC tutorials and it advised me to follow the former as this was the new approach. It looks MCV-ish in that it leads you through creating models and views. But then just runs out of tutorial leaving me trying to guess multiple approaches not really sure which to use as they're all slightly incompatible yet overlapping. Just finding how to create several related models at the same time (simple in Django) is proving a challenge. I'm following your linked tutorial now and scrapping some of the previous approach. I'll close this question. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped. More than happy to help anytime.